# Confusion with Proof of Schur's Lemma

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

I'm following a proof of Schur's lemma as presented in these notes on [Representation Theory and Quantum Mechanics by Noah Miller](https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/noahmiller/files/representation-theory-quantum.pdf). I'll walk through their presentation of the lemma and the proof, to explain what confuses me.

> **Lemma**:
> Suppose we have two irreducible representations,
> \begin{align}
>     &\pi_1: G \rightarrow GL(V_1)\\
>     &\pi_2: G \rightarrow GL(V_2)
> \end{align}
> and suppose there exists an `inter-twining' linear transformation $S:V_1 \rightarrow V_2$ such that,
> \begin{align}
>     S\pi_1(g) = \pi_2(g) S
> \end{align}
> for all $g\in G$. Then the following are true:
>
> 1. If $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are inequivalent, then $S=\mathbf{0}$.
> 2. If $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ (implying that $V_1=V_2$) are equivalent then $S = \mathbf{1}\lambda$ where $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$

It's just the proof of 1. that I'm concerned with in this question.

> **Proof of 1**:
> For all $v_1 \in \mathrm{ker}(S)$
> \begin{align}
>     S\pi_1(g)v_1 = \pi_2(g) Sv_1 = \pi_2(g)0 = 0
> \end{align}
> therefore $(\pi_1(g) v_1) \in \mathrm{ker}(S)$.

> For all $v_2 \in \mathrm{Im}(S)$, there exists a $v_1$ such that $S(v_1) = v_2$.
> \begin{align}
>     \pi_2(g) v_2 = \pi_2(g) S(v_1) = S(\pi_1(g) v_1) \in \mathrm{Im}(S) 
> \end{align}

My confusion lies with this statement. Why is it that $S(\pi_1(g) v_1) \in \mathrm{Im}(S)$? What's stopping $\pi_1(g) v_1 \in \ker S$ from being true in this line? Certainly $v_1 \notin \ker S$, given how $v_1$ was defined as $S(v_1) = v_2 \in \mathrm{Im}(S)$. But couldn't the action of $\pi_1(g)$ take $v_1$ to $\ker S$?

The proof carries on,

> Thus $\pi_1(g)(\mathrm{ker}(S)) \in \ker S$ and $\pi_2(g)(\mathrm{Im} S) \in \mathrm{Im}S$. This proves that $\ker S$ is a sub-representation of $\pi_1$ and that $\mathrm{Im} S$ is a sub-representation of $\pi_2$. Since these are irreducible representations, any sub-representation would have to be the trivial one $\mathbf{0}$ or the vector space itself.  This leaves only two possibilities,
>
> 1. $\ker S = 0$ and $\mathrm{Im} S = V_2$, but then $S$ would be invertible by definition. Then we could write $S \pi_1(g) S^{-1} = \pi_2(g)$ and this contradicts the opening salvo that these two representations are inequivalent (i.e. not related by a similarity transformation).
> 2. $\ker S = V_1$ and $\mathrm{Im}S = 0$, which confirms that $S = \mathbf{0}$.

which I'm fine with.

Comment: $S(\text{anything})\in\text{Im}(S)$

Comment: I'd also recommend that you _not_ interpret an isomorphism of $\pi_1$ to $\pi_2$ to mean that the vector spaces they act on are "identical". E.g., even if they are literally the same vector space, that does _not_ imply that the intertwining is a scalar, since the two repns could differ by a conjugation, etc. This is a pointless mess to get into...

Comment: @StinkingBishop Oh I think that's actually where I was confused. I was somehow thinking that $0 \notin \mathrm{Im}\,S$ by definition. Just basic facts of linear algebra then. In my head, for a linear operator, $S \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$, the space $V$ can be subdivided into $\ker S$ and the 'rest' which are vectors that $S$ maps to non-null vectors, and this is called $\mathrm{Im}\, S$. Clearly that's not right.

Comment: @paulgarrett Wouldn't it be useful for me, who comes to this from physics, to think of them as identical spaces though? If I have have two subspaces of physical states, coming from say two distinct physical systems, respectively, then it could be of some utility to think of the two subspaces as being made up of the same physical states just duplicated between the two systems. This is of course if it happened to be identified that each subspace transforms under the same irrep of some symmetry group.

Comment: @samporterbridges, that identification is certainly _approximately_ good, but/and, for example, $\pi_2(g)=A\pi_1(g)A^{-1}$ corresponds to $V\to V$ by $v\to Av$. This might seem to contradict Schur's lemma, but it does not. :)